# Geting total row count in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
$rowCount = $conn->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users');
echo '<pre>'.print_r($rowCount,1).'</pre>';
```

returns:

```
mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 1
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 1
    [type] => 0
)
```

... although the table has **978** rows as I see in PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: there's only one row in `count(*)`.  What you want is the result, not the number of rows

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using print_r  to generate the number of rows in your query.  Your query is only returning one row, which is the count of rows.

Try this:

```
$rowCount = $conn->query('SELECT COUNT(*) as rowNumber FROM Users');
$row = $rowCount->fetch_assoc();
echo $row['rowNumber'];
```

Comment: I am late for answer, you did well before me :(

Answer (score -1):

query returns an object, you need to fetch the result from that object

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM Users";

if ($res = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    /* Fetch object array */
    while ($obj = $res->fetch_object()) {
        echo '<pre>'.print_r($obj->count,1).'</pre>';
    }
    $res->close();
}
```